# It is not permitted to call Browser.inputBox() from this context

Tags: google-apps-script

In my first experiences with Google Scripts, I'm trying to define a function that call a Browser.input method to get a user name.
But I always get the following error message:

It is not permitted to call Browser.inputBox() from this context.

(I must say that i've translated it from the portuguese environment, for the case there is a different expression for it in english).

I'd appreciate if someone could advise me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share some code? How are you running this? In a spreadsheet or as a web app?

Comment: Thanks Arun.
I've just completed my question with some script code.
I'm executing it in the Script Editor and from a Site with a link pointing to the script.

Comment: I've just implemented it also as a web application and tested it, but i've got the same error msg.

Answer (score 1):

`Browser.inputBox()` can only be used from a script running from a spreadsheet. Once you use a Ui (with UiApp or GUI builder or HTML service) you can't use these `Browser` methods.
The only situation in wich they can be combined is when you `show(app)` from a spreadsheet script but then the `Browser` call will close the UI immediately.

This seems quite logical since they are in a way  Ui themselves...

By the way, you say in your comment that you are updating your question with some code but I see nothing ? Is it normal ?

---

***EDIT :*** to answer your comment, there are many ways to interact with users... something that is quite similar to `Browser.message` is the [popup example proposed by Waqar Ahmad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641306/how-to-make-the-google-ui-services-popuppanel-works) recently.
As for your second point : where to find such information... well I guess I've read about everything that can be read on the subject for quite a moment now.... I'm not sure where that particular aspect is described, sorry about that. If you read Google documentation about Ui I'm pretty sure you'll find something about that. *(maybe someone from the team could help me on that point ? ;-)*

Comment: Thanks Serge. 
I don't what happen with the code i'm sure i added to the body of my question, but I've just tested your explanation and as expected it does ok.
So, please, let me ask: in the script editor or from a web app which methods can be used to interact with the user to accept data?
And, second, where can I obtain the type of information you send me before about the Browser object?
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thanks once more Serge.
I just hope that you believe I've tried the regular documentation, like Tutorials and the API Reference. But of course i'll continue the search for an answer. 
Meanwhile, if someone could suggest the right one, it will bw "gold over blue", to use a portuguese saying.

Comment: In french we use to say 'the cherry on the cake' (la cerise sur le gâteau) ;-)

Comment: ok, that's another way of saying it, that we also know as
"A cereja em cima do bolo!"