# Browser.inputBox is not working in doPost in app scripting for spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script

```
Browser.inputBox('Enter your name', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL)
```

Above Code is working fine in `sendSurvey` function.

But I am trying to use it in `doPost` method in app scripting for spreadSheets. It is not working there.

Can anyone tell me why it is not woking?

[image: my execution transcript is showing this]

but I am not getting my input box.

Answer (score 1):

See the answer here: [browserbox-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655478/it-is-not-permitted-to-call-browser-inputbox-from-this-context)

You can use the input box in the context of a Google Spreadsheet, or a custom function within the Google Apps UI. When you're making a POST() request, that is invalid since the context is serving the request directly, with a text or html output. You can't have a inputbox popup with that.