# Missing ) after formal parameters. (line 1, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to make a count down clock using a user input to start it on Google Apps Script (Which uses JavaScript).  And I'm getting the error (I think it is Syntax):
"Missing ) after formal parameters. (line 1, file "Code")"
Here is my code:

```
function COUNTD(Browser.inputBox(prompt))
{
  var clock = Browser.inputBox("Intiate countdown sequence?");

  if(clock == "yes")
  {
    return("T - 30 minutes and counting...");
  }
  if(count == "abort")
  {
    return("Countdown aborted")
  }

}
```

I know there are multiple variations of this question, but I couldn't user the answers given for those and apply them to mine.

Am I just being really stupid?

Comment: That syntax doesn't make sense (and is erroneous). The "formal" parameter list in a  function declaration must be a list of identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need here is something like this:

```
function COUNTD(bInputBox)
{
  var clock = bInputBox("Intiate countdown sequence?");

  if(clock == "yes")
  {
    return("T - 30 minutes and counting...");
  }
  if(count == "abort")
  {
    return("Countdown aborted")
  }

}

COUNTD(Browser.inputBox);
```

Comment: Royson, this helped to solve the original problem, however now it is saying: "Method "inputBox" was invoked with [object Object] as "this" value that cannot be converted to type Browser. (line 3)."

Comment: @TheSatIsBack I'm not sure about the above error since I'm out of context here but I hope the following answer solves your query: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13658770/6080889