# Not replacing e.parameter

Tags: google-apps-script

I created this script to be able to send an email after a grid has been filled with information. Before the email is sent, another display comes in an warns the user to continue only if the information is correct. At the end the script sends an email to me, with the info entered by the user. The problem is here, when I received the email, the fields that the script is suppose to replace are shown as undefined and no info is there. Any ideas on what is wrong here??
Thank you!

```
function runmyapp() {
 var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Title 1');
  var grid = app.createGrid(4, 5);
  grid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Time '));
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('Time'));
  grid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Minutes'));
  grid.setWidget(1, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('Minutes'));
  grid.setWidget(2, 0, app.createLabel('Enter Name'));
  grid.setWidget(2, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('Name'));
  grid.setWidget(3, 0, app.createLabel('Email'));
  grid.setWidget(3, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('email'));
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  panel.add(grid);

  var button = app.createButton('Submit').setId("button");
  var handler2 = app.createServerHandler('dis');
  handler2.addCallbackElement(grid);
  button.addClickHandler(handler2); 
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('disc');
  handler.addCallbackElement(grid);
  button.addClickHandler(handler);   

  // Add the button to the panel and the panel to the application, then display the                              application app
    panel.add(button);
    app.add(panel);
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheet.show(app);
  }

function dis(e){
 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   app.getElementById("button").setText("Request is in process, please     wait!").setEnabled(false);
   return app;
   }; 

function disc(e){
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var html1 = app.add(app.createHTML("<p><p>Hello Expert,</p>"+
"<p>By clicking OK you agree that your information is correct</p>");
    var button = app.createButton('Ok').setId("button");
    app.add(button);
    var handler2 = app.createServerHandler('gsnot');
    button.addClickHandler(handler2); 
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheet.show(app);
  return app;}




  function gsnot(e) {
    var advancedArgs = {bcc:e.parameter.email};
    var emailSubject = "Subject";
    var address ="albdominguez25@gmail.com";

    var emailTemplate     =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Templates").getRange("A1").getValue(    ) ; 
    emailTemplate = emailTemplate.replace("TIME", e.parameter.Times).replace("MIN",     e.parameter.Minutes).replace("EXP", e.parameter.Name);   

    MailApp.sendEmail(address, emailSubject, emailTemplate, advancedArgs);

    Browser.msgBox("Your Email has been sent!");

    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    app.close();
    // The following line is REQUIRED for the widget to actually close.
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheet.show(app);
  }
```

Comment: As Henrique said, you forgot the callBackelement on the last handler2 (although you had it on handler and handler2 in the main function). Btw why did you re-define it in disc(e) ? You could have 3 handlers, one for each function call...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a widget value show on your `e.parameter` you need to add it (or a parent panel) as a `callback element` on the handler. Like this:

```js
function runmyapp() {
  //...
  var grid = app.createGrid(4, 5).setId('grid');
  //...
}

function disc(e){
  //...
  var grid = app.getElementById('grid');
  var handler2 = app.createServerHandler('gsnot').addCallbackElement(grid);
  //...
}
```

Comment: ty, that really worked! another question related, how would I be able to clear the grid, and stored the data entered while I display the warning without the textboxes? is it possible?

Comment: well, it is surely possible. Although I understood little of of your explaination. Anyway, this probably deserves its own question, with a code example of your attempt and a longer explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**Keep Henrique's answer as best one please**.
You can try to change your `disc(e)` function like this :

```
function disc(e){
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var html1 = app.add(app.createHTML("<p><p>Hello Expert,</p>"+
"<p>By clicking OK you agree that your information is correct</p>"));
    var grid = app.getElementById('grid')
    var button = app.createButton('Ok').setId("button");
    app.add(button);
    var handler3 = app.createServerHandler('gsnot');// use a different name to avoid confusion
    handler3.addCallbackElement(grid);
    button.addClickHandler(handler3); 
  return app;}
```

And, also, there is a typo in your code in this line :

```
emailTemplate = emailTemplate.replace("TIME", e.parameter.Times).replace("MIN",     e.parameter.Minutes).replace("EXP", e.parameter.Name);
```

`Time` has no 's' at the end in the original name ! ;)

and, last point, if I where you I wouldn't call `show(app)` in `disc` so the UI would keep the data validation while confirming... (but that's a matter of choice ;-)

Comment: This worked too, but the warning is displayed within the active uiapp, I was wondering if is possible to display the warning in another uiapp, while keeping the data stored and once it gets to the gsnot function still be able to replace the values from e.parameter..

Comment: you can use a popup (or better the popup emulation described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692563/how-to-move-a-popup-window-from-a-client-handler) within the main UI to show the warning... it should look nice ;-)