# Positioning a form over a google spreadsheet programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet with a form that pops up to receive data and it works fine.  My problem is that it pops up in the center of the spreadsheet and I would prefer it to pop up off to the right of the spreadsheet.  Is there code available to accomplish this?

Comment: see this post answer : [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692563/how-to-move-a-popup-window-from-a-client-handler)

Comment: Are you using a standard Google form linked to a spreadsheet or a form designed with uiapp?  I though it was the 2d option of course...otherwise how can you have the form masking the SS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to control the position of the form.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I've searched everywhere.  I was looking for something along the lines of UiApp.createApplication().setPosition(xcoord, ycoord);  Someone should write it  :)

Comment: You can file a request on the issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll do that.  I believe it would be most helpful.