# How to know which element called the callback function?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script creating buttons in a table. 
Each button is assigned to the same callback server function. 
My question is how do I know which of these buttons triggered the server call?

Also is there a way of outputting a msgbox from the server script? When I try browser.msgBox, it gives an error saying that msgbox can't be used in this context.

```
var clientDel = app.createServerHandler("delStudent").addCallbackElement(grid);
table.setWidget(t, 4, app.createButton("Delete", clientDel).setId("del1"));

function delStudent(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  e.
  return app;
}
```

Thanks,
C Singh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. simply `e.parameter.source` will return the ID of the widget that originates the handler function
2. You can use a label or a textBox that you create in your UI and set invisible. Then at any moment you can use `getElementById(label_ID').setVisible(true)` and put any text in it.

If you want it to appear at a specific position above all other widgets you can do that quite simply using `setStyleAttributes`, see [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692563/how-to-move-a-popup-window-from-a-client-handler)(server version) for further info and practical example