# apps-script: handling confirmation dialogs and errors?

Tags: google-apps-script

There's no `Alert` in apps-script, and `Browser.msgBox` [only works in spreadsheets](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=2&q=1043&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&id=1043).

So, how do people handle confirmation dialogs, and so on? Surely there's got to be a better way than popping up and deleting new widgets?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you have in mind exactly when asking for an equivalent of `Browser.msgBox` (which in my opinion is nothing else than a panel with a couple of Label in it...) but maybe [this workaround](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxFFUTFpbOeslwKnaVRxKcZYPCqYvqh7LZfwN-Om_-tne2I0TLA/exec) could please you ? It's just a "real situation" example that can be fully customized of course... code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692563/how-to-move-a-popup-window-from-a-client-handler)

Comment: Hi Serge - thanks - works great. 2.5 years since the fixed position bug was reported, and no progress.